# Quantum point contacts (QPC) conductance smearing

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nanoscience

I have a question regarding the smearing of conductance plateaus of quantum point contacts (QPC).
Conductance plateaus smear if the system is at a finite temperature $T > 0$ K.
What is the exact mechanism behind it? Does the transmission behavior of the charge carriers change with temperature?
Can the plateaus also become smeared when a small source drain ac bias is applied, since the charge carriers receive additional energy from the bias?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, at zero temperarure, the tunneling is solely determined by the geometric parameters of the quantum point contact (QPC), namely its aspect ratio. Beenakker et al delivered a concise theoretical treatment of this.

The analysis typically follows the lines of

- assume that at zero temperarure the de-Broglie wavelength is orders of magnitude larger than the dimensions of the constriction.
- write the geometry of the system as a potential in the shape of a saddle.
- quantize the wave functions in the direction perpendicular to the opening.
- use the quantized energy levels as resonance levels for tunneling.

The smearing happens because above zero temperature the Fermi distribution function is not a sharp step at Fermi energy $E_F$ anymore, but instead has a small tail of occupied states at higher energies. Thus for tunneling to happen, the voltage can be a tiny amount of the order $k_BT $ lower than the resonance level given by the curvatures of the QPC.
If you want to know more, useful keywords might be Landauer-Büttiker equation and transport quantization.

If you apply a small ac-Bias at zero temperature you would not expect the same smearing. You might of course consider the Joule-hearing with conductance element $\sigma=\frac{e^2}{h} $ as an element that increases the temperature by $\sigma V^2$ As you however have an ac-signal things might get more complicated once the frequency becomes an integer multiple of the quantization frequency of the QPC, as in this case resonnt creation and annihilation of quantized levels dramatically changes the transport properties.